# If beforeSpec has fallen, then all tests in the class are not run

Tags: allure, kotest

Often test data is generated in beforeAll and if the methods in it fall, then all tests of this class will not run and this will not be visible in allure reports in any way
I use cat eats as a test framework. Data is generated in beforeSpec by calling neighboring methods. If the method has completed 404 and no data has been generated, kotest throws Before Spec Error and does not run tests in the class. But is there a way for it to run these tests anyway?

I use kotest-extensions-allure, which generates an allure report and information about it will not be visible in it.